# Refresh image if failed to load with Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

How do I detect if the image failed to load in Firefox or IE and I want to refresh the page using vbscript?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox can't be remotely controlled via VBScript. What are you trying to achieve? For automating website checks something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) might be a better choice.

Comment: IE supports automation via the [`InternetExplorer.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM object. However, I'm not sure if what you want is doable even with that.